# Наследование класса, имя которого берется из переменной

Tags: python, наследование

Требуется создать класс с наследованием, где имя наследуемого класса является переменным параметром.

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Может быть для этого существует более подходящее решение?

Comment: Да, было внутреннее ощущение, что это как-то не правильно.
Решил с функцией type. Но в последствии всё таки нашёл другой более правильный путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

```
class X:
    a = 1

name = 'NewClass'
bases = (list, X, )

NewClass = type(name, bases, {})

newclass_instance = NewClass([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Спасибо. именно то, что было нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, зачем вам это может понадобиться, но получить класс по имени можно в словаре `globals()`:

```
class A:
    pass

def test(cname):
    # Получаем класс, от которого нужно унаследовать.
    c = globals().get(cname, None)
    if c is None:
        return None

    # Создаем наследника.
    class B(c):
        pass
    return B

x = test('A')
print(x, x.__bases__)
```

Выдает такое:

```
$ python test.py
<class '__main__.test.<locals>.B'> (<class '__main__.A'>,)
```